# Keep main file open when doing Save As in excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there any way to keep main file open when doing `Save as` in excel. When you do `Save as` excel is switching to saved file and I need to manually open previous file, from one that I did `Save as`. Is there any way to keep both files open?

Comment: there are some vba solutions here http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-12252.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to keep both files open at the same time.

But you can use the code below to keep the original file open （But the saved file does not open）

```
Sub save()
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "Original file address"
End Sub
```

[image]

I hope it helps you.